# Svg elements are not displaying as espected

Tags: svg

I have created several SVG's in inkscape and saved the generated paths to my DB. When I display them on there seems to be no consistancy to their starting axis

NOTE:

- the horizontal pic is for showing how far off the Y axis are off
- the vertial pic shows how far the X axis are off
- I have clipped the vertical to save space
- the red css border is to help show the dispariaty in starting location

[image: the a-z of svgs horizontally]

[image: the a-g of svgs vertically]

Initially the problem was much worse so to fix it I set all the starting coordinates to `m 10,10` (this got me to where I am now) and noticed that I can manually alter each of the letters starting X Y coordinate to place it where I want it to be, however I would like to try and understand why they are not uniform when I have defined the same starting location?

I have added `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"` and also tried every value for preserveAspectRatio but none seem to have any effect. In addition to this (after reading seeveral tutorials and SO posts) I also tried adding an additional namespace `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` but this had no effect.

I would like to display all letters in the center of the viewport without manually altering each svg starting coordinates, can it be done? If the answer is no what do I need to do to be able to display them in a straight line (on the horizontal/vertical)?

below is a link to my [codepen](https://codepen.io/tony-simpson/pen/jOqrabJ) which shows problem. The charaters 'a' 'b' and 'q' are used as I think they are good examples: (note: I tried to add the 3 svg's directly to the question but it exceeded the allowed charater count)

https://codepen.io/tony-simpson/pen/jOqrabJ

Comment: Would you consider using javascript?

Comment: I'm happy to consider any solution. But I feel that I have done something wrong in the creation of the elements and would like to find out the reason

Comment: I see you already have an answer with javascript. I do not think you have done anything wrong with the paths, it is just that you cannot control how Inkscape prepares those paths. They always start at `10, 10`, but which point is the first? Top left? bottom right? center? You have no control over that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to center the path in the middle of the svg canvas. For example for the letter A you can do:

```js
//get the bounding box for the letter A
let bba = a.getBBox()
//translate the letter A in the middle od the svg canvas. The number 10 used representd half width or half height as in viewBox="0 0 20 20"
a.setAttribute("transform", `translate(${-bba.x -bba.width/2 + 10},${-bba.y - bba.height/2 +10})`)
```

```css
svg{width:100px; outline:solid}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <path  id="a" d="m 10,10 q 0,0.0207 0,0.031 0.01033,0.0207 0.01033,0.0413 0,0.031 0.01034,0.0413 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 v 0.0103 q 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0,0.0103 0.01033,-0.0103 0.02067,-0.0207 0.05168,-0.062 0.03101,-0.031 0.09302,0 0.06201,0.031 0.09302,0.0724 0.02067,0.0103 0.04134,0.031 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 v -0.0103 q 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 0,-0.031 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0413 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0517 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0517 0,-0.0207 0,-0.062 0,-0.031 0,-0.062 0,-0.031 0,-0.0723 0,-0.031 0,-0.0724 0,-0.031 0,-0.0724 0,-0.0413 0,-0.093 0,-0.0517 -0.01034,-0.0827 -0.01033,-0.0413 -0.01033,-0.0827 0,-0.031 0,-0.0724 -0.01033,-0.0413 -0.02067,-0.0827 0,-0.0413 -0.01033,-0.093 -0.01033,-0.0413 -0.02067,-0.0827 0,-0.0413 -0.01034,-0.093 -0.01034,-0.0517 -0.02067,-0.093 -0.01034,-0.0413 -0.02067,-0.093 0,-0.0413 -0.01033,-0.093 -0.01034,-0.0517 -0.02067,-0.10335 -0.01033,-0.0413 -0.02067,-0.0827 0,-0.0517 -0.01034,-0.10335 0,-0.0517 -0.01033,-0.11369 0,-0.062 -0.02067,-0.12402 -0.01034,-0.062 -0.02067,-0.11369 -0.01033,-0.062 -0.02067,-0.11369 -0.01033,-0.0517 -0.01033,-0.11368 -0.01033,-0.062 -0.02067,-0.12403 -0.01034,-0.062 -0.02067,-0.13436 -0.01033,-0.062 -0.02067,-0.12402 -0.01034,-0.062 -0.01034,-0.12402 0,-0.062 0,-0.13436 -0.01033,-0.0724 -0.01033,-0.13436 -0.01033,-0.062 -0.01033,-0.13436 0,-0.0827 0,-0.15503 -0.01034,-0.0827 -0.02067,-0.1757 -0.01034,-0.0827 -0.02067,-0.16536 -0.01033,-0.0827 -0.01033,-0.1757 -0.01033,-0.093 -0.03101,-0.18604 -0.01033,-0.10335 -0.03101,-0.19637 -0.01034,-0.093 -0.03101,-0.18603 -0.01034,-0.093 -0.02067,-0.18604 -0.01034,-0.093 -0.02067,-0.18603 -0.01033,-0.093 -0.031,-0.18604 -0.01034,-0.093 -0.03101,-0.18603 -0.01034,-0.093 -0.02067,-0.18604 -0.02067,-0.10335 -0.03101,-0.18603 -0.01033,-0.0827 -0.02067,-0.1757 -0.01034,-0.0827 -0.02067,-0.16537 -0.02067,-0.0827 -0.04134,-0.16536 -0.01033,-0.0724 -0.03101,-0.1447 -0.01034,-0.0827 -0.04134,-0.14469 -0.02067,-0.0724 -0.04134,-0.13436 -0.02067,-0.062 -0.04134,-0.11369 -0.02067,-0.062 -0.04134,-0.12402 -0.02067,-0.0517 -0.05168,-0.11369 -0.02067,-0.062 -0.05168,-0.11369 -0.03101,-0.062 -0.06201,-0.11369 -0.03101,-0.0517 -0.05168,-0.10335 -0.03101,-0.0517 -0.05168,-0.093 -0.03101,-0.0517 -0.05168,-0.093 -0.02067,-0.0517 -0.05168,-0.093 -0.02067,-0.0413 -0.04134,-0.0827 -0.02067,-0.0413 -0.04134,-0.0724 -0.01033,-0.0413 -0.03101,-0.0724 -0.02067,-0.031 -0.04134,-0.062 -0.02067,-0.0413 -0.04134,-0.062 -0.01033,-0.0207 -0.03101,-0.0413 -0.01033,-0.0207 -0.03101,-0.0517 -0.02067,-0.031 -0.05168,-0.062 -0.03101,-0.0207 -0.05168,-0.0413 -0.02067,-0.0103 -0.04134,-0.0207 -0.02067,-0.0103 -0.05168,-0.0103 -0.03101,-0.0103 -0.06201,-0.0103 -0.03101,-0.0103 -0.04134,-0.0103 -0.01034,0 -0.02067,0 -0.01033,0 -0.03101,0.0103 -0.03101,0.0103 -0.04134,0.0103 0,0.0103 0.01033,0 0.01034,-0.0103 -0.01033,-0.0103 -0.03101,0 -0.07235,0.0103 -0.04134,0.0103 -0.06201,0.0207 -0.01033,0.0103 -0.03101,0.0103 -0.02067,0.0103 -0.05168,0.0103 -0.02067,0.0103 -0.04134,0.0207 -0.03101,0.0103 -0.06201,0.0207 -0.04134,0.0103 -0.06201,0.0207 -0.02067,0 -0.04134,0.0103 -0.02067,0.0103 -0.031,0.0207 -0.02067,0.0103 -0.03101,0.0103 -0.02067,0 -0.03101,0.0103 -0.02067,0.0103 -0.05168,0.0207 -0.02067,0.0103 -0.04134,0.0103 -0.01033,0.0103 -0.03101,0.0207 -0.01033,0.0103 -0.04134,0.0207 -0.03101,0.0207 -0.04134,0.0413 -0.02067,0.0103 -0.03101,0.0207 -0.01033,0 -0.03101,0.0207 -0.02067,0.0103 -0.04134,0.031 -0.01033,0.0103 -0.04134,0.031 -0.02067,0.0103 -0.05168,0.0413 -0.02067,0.0207 -0.04134,0.0413 -0.01034,0.0207 -0.03101,0.031 -0.01034,0.0103 -0.03101,0.031 -0.02067,0.031 -0.03101,0.0413 -0.01033,0.0207 -0.02067,0.031 -0.01033,0 -0.03101,0.0413 -0.02067,0.0414 -0.02067,0.062 0,0.0207 -0.01033,0.031 -0.02067,0.0207 -0.02067,0.031 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 -0.01033,0 -0.01033,0.0103 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 -0.01033,0.0103 -0.01033,0.031 0,0.0207 0,0.0103 0,-0.0103 -0.01034,-0.0103 0,0 -0.02067,0.031 -0.01034,0.0413 -0.02067,0.062 0,0.0103 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.02067,0.0207 -0.02067,0.0517 -0.01033,0.0207 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.02067,0.031 -0.03101,0.062 -0.01034,0.0413 -0.02067,0.0723 -0.01034,0.0207 -0.02067,0.0517 -0.01033,0.031 -0.01033,0.062 -0.01033,0.0207 -0.03101,0.062 -0.02067,0.031 -0.03101,0.0724 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.03101,0.0724 -0.01034,0.0207 -0.03101,0.062 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.04134,0.0827 -0.01034,0.0413 -0.02067,0.0724 -0.01033,0.031 -0.03101,0.062 -0.02067,0.031 -0.03101,0.062 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.03101,0.0724 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.031,0.0724 -0.02067,0.031 -0.03101,0.062 -0.01034,0.0413 -0.02067,0.062 -0.01033,0.0207 -0.03101,0.0517 -0.02067,0.031 -0.04134,0.062 -0.02067,0.031 -0.04134,0.062 -0.02067,0.031 -0.04134,0.0724 -0.02067,0.0517 -0.04134,0.0827 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.04134,0.093 -0.03101,0.0413 -0.04134,0.0723 -0.01033,0.0414 -0.031,0.0724 -0.02067,0.0207 -0.04134,0.062 -0.02067,0.031 -0.03101,0.062 -0.01034,0.031 -0.04134,0.062 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.031,0.0827 -0.02067,0.0517 -0.03101,0.0724 -0.01034,0.031 -0.02067,0.062 -0.01033,0.031 -0.02067,0.062 -0.01034,0.0413 -0.02067,0.0724 -0.01033,0.031 -0.02067,0.062 -0.02067,0.031 -0.031,0.0724 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.04134,0.093 -0.03101,0.0413 -0.05168,0.093 -0.02067,0.0517 -0.04134,0.10335 -0.01033,0.0413 -0.03101,0.0827 -0.01033,0.0413 -0.03101,0.093 -0.03101,0.0413 -0.04134,0.093 -0.01033,0.0413 -0.02067,0.0724 -0.01033,0.0413 -0.031,0.0827 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.04134,0.0724 -0.01033,0.031 -0.03101,0.0827 -0.03101,0.0413 -0.04134,0.0724 -0.01033,0.0413 -0.031,0.0827 -0.01034,0.0413 -0.02067,0.0827 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.02067,0.0724 -0.01033,0.031 -0.02067,0.0517 -0.01034,0.031 -0.03101,0.062 -0.01033,0.0413 -0.02067,0.0723 0,0.0207 -0.01034,0.0413 -0.01033,0.0103 -0.03101,0.0517 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.03101,0.0827 -0.01033,0.031 -0.02067,0.0517 0,0.0103 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.01033,0.031 -0.02067,0.062 -0.01034,0.031 -0.03101,0.0517 -0.02067,0.0207 -0.03101,0.062 -0.02067,0.031 -0.04134,0.0724 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.03101,0.0723 -0.01033,0.031 -0.02067,0.062 -0.02067,0.0207 -0.03101,0.062 -0.02067,0.031 -0.031,0.062 -0.01034,0.0207 -0.03101,0.0517 -0.01034,0.031 -0.02067,0.062 -0.01033,0.031 -0.03101,0.062 -0.01033,0.031 -0.02067,0.0724 0,0.0413 0,0.0517 0,0.0207 -0.01034,0.031 -0.01033,0.0207 -0.02067,0.0517 0,0.031 0,0.0413 -0.01033,0.0103 -0.02067,0.031 0,0.0207 -0.01033,0.0413 -0.01033,0.0207 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.02067,0.0207 -0.02067,0.0414 -0.01033,0.0207 -0.01033,0.031 0,0.0103 -0.01034,0.0207 -0.01033,0.0207 -0.02067,0.0517 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.01034,0.0517 0,0.0207 -0.01033,0.0103 v 0.0103 q 0,0.0103 -0.01033,0.0207 -0.01033,0.0103 -0.02067,0.0517 -0.02067,0.031 -0.02067,0.0413 0,0.0103 -0.01034,0.031 0,0.0103 -0.02067,0.031 -0.01033,0.0207 -0.02067,0.0517 -0.01033,0.031 -0.02067,0.0517 -0.01034,0.031 -0.02067,0.0517 -0.01033,0.0207 -0.02067,0.031 -0.01034,0.0207 -0.02067,0.062 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.01033,0.0517 0,0.0207 -0.01034,0.031 -0.01033,0.0207 -0.02067,0.062 -0.01034,0.0413 0,0.0413 0,0.0103 -0.01034,0.031 0,0.0207 0,0.031 0,0.0103 -0.01034,0.031 0,0.0207 0,0.0517 -0.01033,0.031 0,0.0207 l -0.01033,0.0103 q 0,0.0103 0,0.0413 -0.01033,0.031 -0.01033,0.0413 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0,0.0103 0.01033,0 0.01033,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 -0.01033,0.0103 -0.02067,0.0517 -0.01033,0.0413 -0.01033,0.0517 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0,0.0207 0,0.031 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0,0.0103 0,0.0103 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 v 0.0103 q 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0,0.0103 0,0.0103 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 v 0.0103 q 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0.02067,0.031 0.04134,0.0517 0.04134,0.0413 0.08268,0.0827 0.05168,0.0413 0.01033,0 -0.03101,-0.0413 -0.07235,-0.0724 -0.04134,-0.0413 0.04134,-0.031 0.08268,0 0.113688,0.0413 0.04134,0.031 0.05168,0.031 0.02067,-0.0207 0.04134,-0.0413 0.04134,-0.0413 0.04134,-0.0517 -0.02067,-0.0207 -0.04134,-0.0414 -0.02067,-0.0207 -0.04134,-0.0517 -0.01034,0 0.031,0.0413 0.04134,0.031 0,0.0724 -0.04134,0.031 -0.07235,0.0723 -0.03101,0.0413 -0.06201,0.0207 -0.03101,-0.0207 0,-0.0207 0.03101,0 0.07235,0.0207 0.03101,0.0103 0.02067,0.0207 -0.02067,0.0103 0.01034,0 0.02067,-0.0103 0.031,-0.0103 0,-0.0103 -0.01033,0 -0.01033,0.0103 -0.04134,-0.031 -0.04134,-0.0413 -0.06201,-0.0413 -0.02067,0 -0.02067,0.0103 h 0.01033 q 0,0.0103 0.08268,0.0103 0.08268,0.0103 0.06201,-0.031 -0.01033,-0.031 -0.07235,0 -0.06201,0.0413 -0.04134,0.0723 0.02067,0.031 0.05168,0.0517 0.04134,0.0103 0.08268,0.0103 0.04134,-0.0103 0.07235,-0.031 0.031,-0.031 0.05168,-0.062 0.01033,-0.0413 0.01033,-0.0827 -0.01033,-0.0414 -0.03101,-0.0724 -0.031,-0.031 -0.02067,0 0.01033,0.0207 -0.05168,0.0517 -0.06201,0.031 -0.08268,0 -0.01033,-0.031 0.06201,-0.031 0.07235,0 0.07235,-0.0103 v -0.0103 q -0.01033,0 -0.03101,-0.0207 -0.02067,-0.0103 -0.07235,-0.0517 -0.04134,-0.0413 -0.07235,-0.031 -0.02067,0.0103 -0.04134,0.0103 -0.01033,0.0103 0.01034,0 0.02067,-0.0103 -0.01034,0 -0.03101,0.0103 0,0.031 0.02067,0.0207 0.04134,0 0.02067,-0.0103 -0.02067,-0.031 -0.03101,-0.0207 -0.08268,0.0207 -0.04134,0.0413 -0.08268,0.0827 -0.04134,0.0413 0,0.093 0.02067,0.0207 0.04134,0.0413 0.01033,0 -0.03101,-0.0413 -0.02067,-0.0103 -0.04134,-0.031 0,0.0103 0.04134,-0.031 0.04134,-0.031 0.03101,-0.031 0.02067,0.0207 0.04134,0.0413 0.04134,0.0413 0.113688,0.0413 0.08268,-0.0103 0.04134,-0.0517 -0.04134,-0.0413 -0.08268,-0.0827 -0.04134,-0.0413 -0.01034,0 0.03101,0.0413 0.07235,0.0723 0.02067,0.0207 0.04134,0.031 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,0 0,-0.0103 v -0.0103 q 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,0 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 v -0.0103 q 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 0,-0.031 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 -0.01033,0 -0.01034,0.0207 0,0.0103 0.01033,-0.0207 0.02067,-0.0517 0.01034,-0.0413 0.01034,-0.0517 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 -0.01034,0 0,0 0.01034,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 0.01033,-0.031 0,-0.031 0,-0.0413 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0.01034,-0.0207 0.01034,-0.031 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0414 0.01033,-0.0207 0.01033,-0.0517 0,-0.0207 -0.01033,-0.0207 0.01033,0 0.01033,-0.0103 0.01034,-0.0207 0.01034,-0.0413 0,-0.0207 0.01033,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 0.01033,-0.031 0.02067,-0.0207 0.03101,-0.0413 0.01033,-0.031 0.02067,-0.062 0.01034,-0.0207 0.02067,-0.0413 0.01034,-0.031 0.02067,-0.0413 0.01033,-0.0207 0.02067,-0.0517 0.01034,-0.0207 0.02067,-0.0517 0,-0.0207 0.01033,-0.031 -0.01033,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0.01034,0 0.02067,-0.031 0.02067,-0.031 0.02067,-0.0517 0.01034,-0.0207 0.01034,-0.0413 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 l 0.01034,-0.0103 q 0.01033,-0.0207 0.02067,-0.0414 0.01033,-0.031 0.01033,-0.0413 0,-0.0103 0.01033,-0.0207 0.01033,-0.0207 0.02067,-0.0413 0.02067,-0.031 0.03101,-0.062 0.01034,-0.031 0.02067,-0.0517 0,-0.031 0.01033,-0.0517 0,-0.0207 0.01034,-0.0517 0.01033,-0.031 0.02067,-0.062 0,-0.031 0,-0.0413 0,-0.0103 0.01034,-0.031 0.01033,-0.0207 0.02067,-0.0413 0.01034,-0.0207 0.02067,-0.0517 0.02067,-0.031 0.03101,-0.062 0.01034,-0.031 0.02067,-0.0517 0.02067,-0.031 0.04134,-0.0724 0.01034,-0.031 0.02067,-0.0724 0.01033,-0.031 0.03101,-0.062 0.01033,-0.0207 0.02067,-0.0413 0.01034,-0.031 0.04134,-0.062 0.02067,-0.0413 0.031,-0.0724 0.01034,-0.0413 0.03101,-0.062 0.01034,-0.031 0.03101,-0.0724 0.01033,-0.0413 0.02067,-0.062 0,-0.031 0.01033,-0.0413 0.01034,-0.0207 0.03101,-0.062 0.02067,-0.031 0.03101,-0.062 0,-0.031 0.02067,-0.062 0.01034,-0.0207 0.02067,-0.062 0.02067,-0.0413 0.03101,-0.0723 0.01033,-0.031 0.02067,-0.0724 0.01034,-0.0413 0.02067,-0.0724 0.02067,-0.0413 0.02067,-0.062 0.01034,-0.031 0.03101,-0.0724 0.02067,-0.031 0.04134,-0.0723 0.01034,-0.031 0.03101,-0.0827 0.03101,-0.0413 0.04134,-0.093 0.02067,-0.0414 0.03101,-0.0827 0.01034,-0.0413 0.03101,-0.0827 0.02067,-0.0413 0.04134,-0.093 0.01034,-0.0413 0.03101,-0.0827 0.01033,-0.0413 0.03101,-0.0827 0.02067,-0.0413 0.05168,-0.093 0.02067,-0.0517 0.04134,-0.10335 0.02067,-0.0413 0.031,-0.0827 0.02067,-0.0413 0.03101,-0.0724 0.01034,-0.0413 0.02067,-0.0724 0.01033,-0.031 0.02067,-0.062 0.01034,-0.031 0.02067,-0.062 0.01033,-0.031 0.02067,-0.0517 0,-0.031 0.02067,-0.0517 0.02067,-0.031 0.04134,-0.062 0.02067,-0.0413 0.03101,-0.0723 0.01033,-0.0207 0.03101,-0.062 0.03101,-0.031 0.04134,-0.0724 0.02067,-0.0413 0.04134,-0.0827 0.02067,-0.031 0.04134,-0.0724 0.02067,-0.0413 0.04134,-0.0827 0.02067,-0.031 0.04134,-0.062 0.02067,-0.031 0.03101,-0.0724 0.02067,-0.031 0.04134,-0.062 0.02067,-0.031 0.04134,-0.0724 0.02067,-0.0413 0.03101,-0.0724 0.01033,-0.031 0.03101,-0.062 0.01033,-0.0207 0.031,-0.062 0.01034,-0.0413 0.03101,-0.0724 0.01034,-0.031 0.03101,-0.062 0.01034,-0.031 0.03101,-0.0827 0.02067,-0.0413 0.03101,-0.0724 0,-0.031 0.02067,-0.062 0.02067,-0.031 0.04134,-0.0724 0.02067,-0.0413 0.031,-0.0827 0.01034,-0.031 0.03101,-0.062 0.02067,-0.031 0.03101,-0.0724 0.01033,-0.0413 0.02067,-0.0724 0.01033,-0.031 0.03101,-0.0723 0.01033,-0.031 0.01033,-0.0517 0,-0.0207 0.01033,-0.0413 0.02067,-0.0207 0.02067,-0.0517 0.01033,-0.0207 0.03101,-0.0413 0.01034,-0.0207 0.02067,-0.0413 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0.01033,-0.0103 0.02067,-0.0207 0.01033,-0.0207 0.03101,-0.062 0.01033,-0.0413 0.01033,-0.0517 -0.01033,0 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0103 0.01033,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 0.02067,-0.0207 0.01033,-0.0207 0,-0.031 0,-0.0103 0,0 0,0.0207 0.01033,0 0.02067,-0.0103 0.03101,-0.031 0,-0.0103 0.02067,-0.0207 0.01034,-0.0103 0.02067,-0.031 0.02067,-0.0207 0.04134,-0.0413 0.01033,-0.0207 0.02067,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 0.02067,-0.0207 0.01034,0 0.04134,-0.0207 0.02067,-0.0207 0.05168,-0.0413 0.02067,-0.0103 0.04134,-0.031 0.02067,-0.0103 0.02067,-0.0207 l 0.01033,-0.0103 q 0.01033,-0.0103 0.02067,-0.0103 0.02067,0 0.03101,-0.0103 0.01034,-0.0103 0.02067,-0.0103 0.01033,-0.0103 0.02067,-0.0103 0.01034,0 0.04134,-0.0103 0.03101,-0.0103 0.05168,-0.0207 0.01033,-0.0103 0.03101,-0.0207 0.02067,-0.0103 0.03101,-0.0103 0.02067,-0.0103 0.04134,-0.0103 0.03101,-0.0103 0.06201,-0.0207 0.03101,-0.0103 0.04134,-0.0103 0.02067,-0.0103 0.04134,-0.0103 0.02067,-0.0103 0.04134,-0.0207 0.03101,-0.0103 0.04134,-0.0103 0.01033,-0.0103 0.02067,0 0.02067,-0.0103 0.04134,-0.0103 0.01033,0 0.03101,-0.0103 0.01033,-0.0103 -0.01034,0 -0.02067,0.0103 -0.01033,0.0103 0.01033,0 0.02067,0 0.01033,0 0.02067,0 0,-0.0103 -0.01033,-0.0103 -0.01033,0 0.01033,0.0103 0.01034,0.0103 0.02067,0.0103 h 0.01034 q 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0,0 0.02067,0.0207 0.01033,0.031 0.03101,0.0517 0.01033,0.0207 0.031,0.0517 0.02067,0.031 0.03101,0.0517 0.02067,0.031 0.03101,0.062 0.02067,0.0207 0.04134,0.0724 0.02067,0.0413 0.05168,0.093 0.02067,0.0413 0.04134,0.0827 0.02067,0.0413 0.05168,0.093 0.02067,0.0517 0.05168,0.10335 0.03101,0.0517 0.06201,0.10335 0.031,0.0517 0.05168,0.093 0.02067,0.0517 0.04134,0.10335 0.02067,0.0517 0.04134,0.10336 0.02067,0.0517 0.04134,0.11368 0.02067,0.062 0.04134,0.11369 0.02067,0.062 0.04134,0.12403 0.02067,0.0517 0.04134,0.12402 0.01033,0.0724 0.03101,0.14469 0.01033,0.0724 0.03101,0.1447 0.01033,0.0827 0.02067,0.16536 0.01033,0.0724 0.02067,0.16537 0.01033,0.093 0.03101,0.18603 0.01034,0.093 0.02067,0.18604 0.01033,0.093 0.03101,0.18603 0.01034,0.093 0.02067,0.18604 0.01033,0.093 0.02067,0.18603 0.01033,0.10335 0.03101,0.19637 0.02067,0.093 0.03101,0.18604 0.02067,0.093 0.03101,0.18603 0.02067,0.093 0.02067,0.18604 0.01034,0.0827 0.02067,0.1757 0.01033,0.0827 0.02067,0.16536 0.01034,0.0827 0.01034,0.15503 0.01033,0.062 0.01033,0.1447 0,0.0723 0,0.14469 0.01033,0.0724 0.01033,0.13436 0.01034,0.062 0.01034,0.13436 0,0.062 0.01033,0.13436 0.01034,0.0827 0.02067,0.14469 0.01034,0.0724 0.02067,0.12402 0.01033,0.062 0.02067,0.12403 0,0.062 0.01033,0.12402 0.01033,0.062 0.02067,0.11369 0.01034,0.062 0.02067,0.11369 0.01033,0.0517 0.02067,0.10335 0,0.062 0.01033,0.11369 0,0.0517 0.01033,0.10335 0,0.062 0.01034,0.11369 0.02067,0.0517 0.03101,0.10335 0.01034,0.0413 0.01034,0.093 0.01033,0.0413 0.02067,0.093 0.01033,0.0517 0.02067,0.093 0.01034,0.0414 0.01034,0.0827 0.01033,0.0517 0.02067,0.093 0.01033,0.0413 0.01033,0.0827 0.01033,0.031 0.01033,0.062 0.01034,0.031 0.01034,0.0723 0,0.0517 0.01034,0.093 0.01033,0.031 0.01033,0.062 0,0.031 0,0.0724 0,0.0413 0,0.0724 0,0.0413 0,0.0724 0,0.0413 0,0.0723 0,0.031 0,0.062 0,0.0413 0,0.062 0,0.031 0,0.0517 0,0.031 0,0.0517 0,0.0207 0,0.0413 0,0.0207 0,0.031 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0,0.0103 0,0.0103 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0.01033,0.0207 0.03101,0.0413 0.04134,0.0413 0.113688,0.0724 0.07235,0.0413 0.113688,-0.0103 0.04134,-0.0413 0.06201,-0.0827 0.01034,-0.0413 0.01034,-0.0517 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0414 0,-0.0207 -0.01034,-0.0413 0,-0.0103 0,-0.031 0,-0.0103 -0.01033,-0.0517 0,-0.031 -0.01034,-0.0517 0,-0.0207 -0.02067,-0.062 -0.02067,-0.031 -0.05168,-0.0517 -0.03101,-0.031 -0.07235,-0.031 -0.04134,0 -0.08268,0.0207 -0.03101,0.0207 -0.06201,0.0517 z m 0.981852,-3.58634 q 0.04134,-0.031 0.07235,-0.0724 0.03101,-0.0413 0.02067,-0.0413 -0.02067,0 -0.04134,0.0103 -0.02067,0 -0.02067,0.0103 -0.01033,0 -0.02067,0 -0.01033,-0.0103 -0.03101,-0.0103 -0.03101,0.0103 -0.07235,0.0103 -0.03101,0 -0.08268,0.0103 -0.04134,0.0103 -0.08268,0.0207 -0.05168,0 -0.113688,0.0103 -0.05168,0.0103 -0.113688,0.0207 -0.06201,0.0103 -0.144694,0.0207 -0.07235,0.0103 -0.165365,0.0207 -0.09302,0.0103 -0.186035,0.0207 -0.09302,0.0103 -0.186035,0.031 -0.103353,0.0103 -0.206706,0.0207 -0.09302,0.0207 -0.206706,0.031 -0.113688,0 -0.227376,0.0103 -0.113688,0.0207 -0.217041,0.031 -0.113688,0.0103 -0.227376,0.0207 -0.113688,0.0103 -0.227377,0.0207 -0.124023,0.0207 -0.248046,0.031 -0.113689,0.0103 -0.237712,0.0207 -0.113688,0.0103 -0.237712,0.0207 -0.124023,0.0103 -0.237711,0.0103 -0.113688,0.0103 -0.227376,0.0207 -0.113689,0.0103 -0.227377,0.0103 -0.103353,0 -0.206705,0 -0.09302,0 -0.1757,-0.0103 -0.08268,0 -0.165365,0 -0.07235,0 -0.134359,0 -0.06201,-0.0103 -0.134358,-0.0103 -0.07235,-0.0103 -0.124024,-0.0103 -0.06201,0 -0.113688,0 -0.05168,0 -0.103353,0 -0.04134,0 -0.103353,0.0103 -0.05168,0 -0.103352,0 -0.04134,0.0103 -0.08268,0.0103 -0.04134,0.0103 -0.06201,0.0103 -0.03101,0.0103 -0.06201,0.0103 -0.04134,0 -0.07235,0 -0.04134,0.0103 -0.07235,0.0207 -0.02067,0 -0.04134,0.0103 -0.02067,0 -0.04134,0.0103 -0.03101,0.0103 -0.03101,0.0207 0.01034,0 0,0 0,-0.0103 -0.03101,0.0103 -0.03101,0.0103 -0.06201,0.031 -0.02067,0.0103 -0.04134,0.0517 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.03101,0.0724 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 0,0.0103 0.01033,0.0517 0.01034,0.0413 0.03101,0.0723 0.03101,0.031 0.07235,0.0413 0.04134,0.0103 0.08268,0 0.04134,-0.0103 0.06201,-0.0413 0.03101,-0.031 0.04134,-0.0723 0.01034,-0.0413 0.01034,-0.0517 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,-0.0103 0,-0.0207 0,0.0103 0,0.0207 -0.01034,0.0207 -0.02067,0.0413 -0.01033,0.0207 -0.02067,0.031 -0.02067,0.0103 -0.03101,0.0207 -0.01034,0 0.01033,0 0.02067,-0.0103 0.04134,-0.0207 0.01033,0 0.02067,-0.0103 -0.01034,0.0103 0.01034,0 0.02067,0 0.04134,-0.0103 0.02067,-0.0103 0.03101,-0.0103 0.02067,0 0.05168,0 0.03101,0 0.06201,0 0.04134,-0.0103 0.08268,-0.0103 0.04134,-0.0103 0.08268,-0.0103 0.04134,-0.0103 0.08268,-0.0103 0.04134,0 0.08268,0 0.05168,0 0.103353,0 0.05168,0 0.103353,0 0.05168,0 0.113688,0 0.07235,0.0103 0.134359,0.0103 0.07235,0.0103 0.144694,0.0103 0.08268,0 0.165364,0 0.09302,0 0.186036,0 0.103352,0 0.217041,0 0.113688,0 0.227376,0 0.124023,-0.0103 0.237711,-0.0207 0.113689,-0.0103 0.237712,-0.0207 0.124023,0 0.248047,-0.0103 0.124023,-0.0207 0.237711,-0.031 0.124024,-0.0103 0.248047,-0.0207 0.113688,-0.0103 0.227377,-0.0207 0.113688,-0.0207 0.227376,-0.031 0.113688,-0.0103 0.217041,-0.0207 0.113688,-0.0103 0.227376,-0.0207 0.113688,-0.0103 0.217041,-0.0207 0.103353,-0.0207 0.206706,-0.031 0.09302,-0.0103 0.186035,-0.0207 0.09302,-0.0207 0.1757,-0.031 0.09302,-0.0103 0.1757,-0.0207 0.08268,0 0.144694,-0.0207 0.07235,-0.0103 0.124023,-0.0207 0.06201,0 0.103353,-0.0103 0.05168,-0.0103 0.09302,-0.0207 0.04134,0 0.07235,-0.0103 0.02067,0 0.04134,0 0.01033,0 0.04134,0 0.03101,0 0.06201,-0.0103 0.03101,0 0.03101,-0.0103 h -0.01034 q -0.01033,0 0.04134,-0.031 0.04134,-0.0413 0.08268,-0.093 0.04134,-0.0413 0.03101,-0.0827 -0.01034,-0.0413 -0.04134,-0.0724 -0.031,-0.031 -0.07235,-0.0413 -0.04134,-0.0103 -0.07235,0 -0.04134,0.0103 -0.07235,0.0413 z"></path>
    </svg>
```

Extending this to all your paths you can do

```js
let paths = document.querySelectorAll("svg path")
paths.forEach(p=>{
  let bb = p.getBBox()
p.setAttribute("transform", `translate(${-bb.x -bb.width/2 + 10},${-bb.y - bb.height/2 +10})`)
})
```

In my code I've changed the svg width to 100 because I wanted to see the path. You can change it back to what you need. You can also delete the border. In order to understand what happens please consider adding a border or outline to your svg elements.